# Select and copy all the elements inside Code tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to copy the entire code block using jquery, I already have a script for copy to the clipboard which utilizes the `select()` method. But according to the jquery docs select event is limited to  fields and  boxes.

So I am seeking for a standalone solution to copy all the elements inside the codeblock at once.

This is how my **HTML** looks like.

```
<pre><code id="texttocopy" class="hljs javascript"><span class="hljs-string">'core/base.html'</span>
#some more html
</code></pre>'
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnFloat" id="copybutton"></button>
```

**Script**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {        
            $("#copybutton").click(function () {
                console.log("clicked");

                $("#texttocopy").select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to do this:

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
```

}